# I dont get session object in php

Tags: php, file, session, object, state

i starting with php  and i want get session object in login form, then, i want show values the object session in a php web page but session object not read their values object.

my php file:

```
try {

   $userLogin = new userDto();
   $userLogin->setUsername($_POST["txtUsername"]);
   $userLogin->setPassword($_POST["txtPassword"]);

   if (UserDao::validateLogin($userLogin)) {  

     //if true, the method validateLogin load other values object in data access layer
     //i tried with print_r($userLogin) and show all values (name,age,ocupation, profile etc....).. works

     session_start();

    if ($userLogin->getIdProfile() == 1) {  

        $_SESSION["userClient"] = $userLogin;
        include_once '../Pages/MenuClient.php';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['adminUser'] = $userLogin;
        include_once '../Paginas/MenuAdmin.php';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No exist';
}

} catch (Exception $ex) {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

php web page:

```
  <?php

    include_once '../../Dto/UserDto.php';

     $dto = new UserDto();
     if(isset($_SESSION["userClient"])) {
         $dto = $_SESSION["userClient"];
         echo 'Exist user'; --> works!!
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'+$dto->getName()+'");</script>';  --> not work
     else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("no found");</script>';
     }
    ?>

    <label><?php echo $dto->getName()?></label>   --> not work
    <label value="<?php echo $dto->getName()?>"></label>  --> not work
```

Comment: Where is `session_start()` in your "php web page" ?

Comment: `session_start()` probably shouldn't be wrapped in your logic like that, it should be included on every page where you expect an active session to be present.

Comment: ammm ok, i understant, now works!! thankss